# When i use index.php/User/login its working, But when i use User.login its not working even after removing of index.php in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

When i use 
index.php/User/login its working, But when i use User/login its not working even after removing of index.php in codeigniter, can anyone say what is wrong with my code? its on live server of root directory

my htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

I've been using this code for many years. I think it could work for you.

Comment: Works fine, thanks and also i have to change the config file of apache

AllOverRide None to Alloverride ALL and also i need to change the Mod rewrite,